# Why doesn't my dialog box look the same on my mobile chrome browser?

Tags: css

So This is my problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsaR0.jpg You can see what it should look like and what it actually looks like. It lloks fine on mobile safari? I even develop on chrome, so why doesn't it look like it should. It's not centered it doesn't have padding? Even though its written in the css? Also to view the dialog box you need to submit the forem in the footer. here's my code

https://github.com/spabsa/Chapman-Automotive-Skills-Assessment

Comment: HEY, I am checking your code on Chrome and Safari, working fine on both for me,Looking same

Comment: Thats strange I guess it takes a min to update